# Flutter 2.5 Multiple errors in Androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

Upgrading to flutter 2.5 was throwing me with an error of-

```
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 4070): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
```

when building the app for the first time.

Doing some research I found that the cause was AndroidManifest.xml

```
For those who have difficulty finding this the path is -Your_app\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
```

AndroidManifest.xml is highlighting some fields and suggesting some solutions which have no fields to implement, anyway I have added some of the suggested fields for which I can place the arguments like-  (actually these go with True/ False)

android:allowBackup , android:exported

Then these disappeared, but for those, I don't have any idea what could the argument be, are still in the error/ suggestion.

> Errors
> [image]

> Suggestions

[image]

where can I find the guide to fill up these fields?
Where can I set the API level? I have the **minSdkVersion 24** set already.

Comment: project/android/app/build.gradle insdide defaultConfig here your sdk versions defined

Comment: @AwiasRehman my question is not about the SDK version that is already 24 (minimum) as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade the flutter version.

Comment: That is already 1 (both the version name and code).